# Placing specific strings at a certain index

Tags: python, string

I want to place strings at a certain index. Let's say we start with an empty string `x=""`. Then I want to place the letters a,e,i,o and u at the indexes 0,2,4,6,8 so that I get `x="a e i o u"`. Then, maybe I want to add z,y,x at indices 1,3,5 so that I get `x=azeyixo u`. How can I do this?

Comment: You can't. Python's string is immutable, so you can't write in-place.  In this case, create a list of characters, edit it however you want, and join.

Comment: I thought of that, but there are only so many characters I can use.

Comment: It would be better if you post what you tried (or going to try).

Comment: I would personally go with @CongMa's approach as well. What do you mean by "there are only so many characters I can use"?

Answer (score 3):

You could make a string builder. Here's a start.

```
>>> class MutableString:
...     def __init__(self, s):
...         self._string = s
...         
...     def __setitem__(self, index, s):
...         if index < len(self._string):
...             self._string = self._string[:index] + s + \
...                                self._string[index+len(s):]
...         else:
...             self._string = self._string + ' ' * \
...                                (index -len(self._string)) + s
...         
...     def __str__(self):
...         return self._string
...              
>>> ms = MutableString("hello world!")
>>> print ms
hello world!
>>> ms[6] = "people"
>>> print ms
hello people
>>> ms = MutableString('')
>>> ms[0] = 'a'; ms[2] = 'e'; ms[4] = 'i'; ms[6] = 'o'; ms[8] = 'u'
>>> print ms
a e i o u
>>> ms[1] = 'z'; ms[3] = 'y'; ms[5] = 'x'
>>> print ms
azeyixo u
```

Or using a list of characters as the internal representation of string data:

```
>>> class CharArrayString:
...     def __init__(self, s=''):
...         self._strdata = [ch for ch in s]
... 
...     def __setitem__(self, index, s):
...         s  = [ch for ch in s]
...         sd = self._strdata
...         if type(index) != slice:
...             if index < len(sd):
...                 sd = sd[:index] + s + sd[index + len(s):]
...             else:
...                 sd = sd + [' '] * (index - len(sd)) + s
...         else:
...             sd[index] = s
...             
...         self._strdata = sd
... 
...     def __getitem__(self, index):
...         return ''.join(self._strdata[index])
... 
...     def __str__(self):
...         return ''.join(self._strdata)
... 
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "ca_str('" + str(self) + "')"
...         
...     def __add__(self, s):
...         if isinstance(s, (CharArrayString, str)):
...             return CharArrayString(self._strdata + [ch for ch in s])
...         else:
...             raise TypeError(f"Catenation operation (+) "
...                             f"expected another CharArrayString "
...                             f"or str, but got {type(s)}.")
...
```

This version supports the previous examples of usage, plus slices and catenation via `+`. It's not literally a character array string - more like a character string list object. Anyway:

```
>>> cas = CharArrayString("Hello world!")
>>> cas[::2]
'Hlowrd'
>>> cas[::-1]
'!dlrow olleH'
>>> cas + " Additional text."
ca_str('Hello world! Additional text.')
>>> cas
ca_str('Hello world!')
>>> cas += "Modifying cas."
>>> cas
ca_str('Hello world!Modifying cas.')
>>> cas[3:8] = '12345'
>>> cas
ca_str('Hel12345rld!Modifying cas.')
```

Comment: +1 for your approach on this matter , but why not have `MutableString` inherit from `str` ? This way you can keep all its methods ( `split()` ,  `upper()` , etc )

Comment: str is an immutable type. Inheriting from it and implementing __setitem__() doesn't work because we can't modify the internal representation of the string. Modifying that same function to return a new instance of a derived str won't work either (e.g. s2 = (s1[1] = 'z')). Much easier to make a string builder class that does a few needed operations.

Comment: Yeah , it was just an idea .. a bad one

Comment: Sounded like a good idea to me too at first until i realized the limitation with __setitem__() and other methods. One way to support the methods of the underlying str without subclassing would be to implement __getattr__()  to return the string's attributes wrapped in an object that implements __call__().

Answer (score 0):

```
def join_str(tmp_dict, x):
    lst_x = list(x)
    lst_keys = list(tmp_dict.keys())
    lst_keys = [int(key) for key in lst_keys]
    max_key = max(lst_keys)
    for i in range(len(lst_x), max_key + 1):
        lst_x.append(' ')
    for key in tmp_dict:
        lst_x[key] = tmp_dict[key]
    return ''.join(lst_x)
```

This should do your job although it can be optimized and input should be a dict where key is the index where you want insert element and value should the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

```
def str_index(s, ilist, clist):
    for i, c  in zip(ilist,clist):
        if i < len(s):
            s = s[:i] + c + s[i+1:]
        else:
            s = s + " " * (i - len(s)) + c
    return s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = str_index("", [0,2,4,6,8], ['a','e','i','o','u'])
    x = str_index(x, [1,3,5], ['x','y','z'])
    print(x)
```